# How can i add six controller in an uiscrollview?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller, uipagecontrol

My Question is little bit bigger so apology for that. Now my problem is i have to set a tabbar controller where first tab will contain an UIScrollView with an UIPageControl, until now i have made my tabbar controller with scrollview and uipagecontrol but i am becoming unable to add uiviewcontroller with every page control in the uiscrollview.

Any suggestion and link of source code  is great help for me.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this solution very simply. I have taken one UIScrollview in my main controller where my scroll will work.

1. In viewDidLoad i have take UIscrollview and load first,next and previous controller as a items of the scrolled view.when i scroll, then respected view controller load on the page of the scrollview.
2. I also take a uipagecontroll in the viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

If it's essential for you to have a separate view controller for each page, the proper way to do this is to use view controller containment, whereby you have your scroll view act as a container for the subordinate view controllers. I recommend reading the [`UIViewController` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), particularly the section entitled "Implementing a Container View Controller".

Comment: Thank you very much warrenm. let me try that.